# What's the best way to send commands through TCP Sockets?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, command

What I'm currently doing with my Server and Client is sending commands between them using simple strings to bytes. What it comes down to is basically this (to send a message to the server as an example):

```
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("$msg:Test Message");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
```

And the recieving end encodes back to a string. It recognizes the command by doing this:

```
recievedstring.Split(':')[0]
```

and assuming that `recievedstring.Split(':')[1]` is the argument. If a user entered a colon in their message then it would cut off there. I feel like this is a hacky way to send data between both endpoints. Is there a more standard way to do this? Sorry if I didn't provide enough information, I'm new to this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont necessarily need to deal all data communicated as string, you can communicate data as bytes and later convert bytes to any datatype(as sent by sender).

A better way is to define a protocol (e.g. a packet format) between server and client for each msg. For example, you can define a packet such that first 4 bytes contain length of the message followed by the message of specified length. Your packet format will be [length:data]

On sending side you will need to write length of message first on stream, and then write the actual data, where as on receiving side you will first receive an int (length of data) and then receive that much byte.

Further more, instead of just $msg (as in your case) if there can be multiple types of packets that can be communicated between end points e.g. $command, $notification etc you can also define a field of message type in your packet. Your packet format will become [length:type:data]

Comment: How would I convert the length int to a byte array? Would the length of the length-byte-array always be the same? How would the client know how to separate the type and data?

Comment: you can convert int to byte array in c# using `BitConverter.GetBytes(length)`, and yes its length will be always same i.e. 4 bytes. 
For separating type and data, type can also be an int, and so always will be of 4 bytes length.

Comment: So my packet format would become [typelength:datalength:type:data]? How would the client know how many bytes to read? What I have now is:
`byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length = serverStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
byte[] newbuffer = buffer.Take(length).ToArray();
string returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newbuffer);`

Comment: You can use int as type i.e. 0 for msg, 1 for command, 2 for notification etc like an enum, so you will not need to write type length,
Client will first read 4 bytes (length, and convert to int), than 4 bytes (type, and convert to int), than 'length' bytes of data (since by now you will have length of data), you can create buffer when you have received the data length

Comment: The serverStream.Read method requires me to specify a length as a parameter. Would I specify a length of 8 (to get type and length), then make the buffer based on the length and call Read again? Thank you so much for your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can read twice, 4 bytes each time, and convert both to ints, or you can also read all 8 bytes once and then extract length and type from first 4 and second 4 bytes correspondingly. Its up to you. Once you have the length you can read the remaining data.